# Windows 7 WMI ODBC driver installation?

Tags: windows, sql, wmi, odbc

I am interested leveraging the ease of report production provided by `Microsoft SQL Report Builder`, but I would like `WMI` as an available datasource.  Since `SQL Report Builder` relies only on SQL, I would like to install the `WMI ODBC` driver on Windows 7, but the [instructions from the MSFT site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) must cover XP, as the `WMI ODBC` driver is not apparently available.

How do I install the `WMI ODBC` driver on Windows 7?

Comment: Howdy "close" voters: I posted this to `stackoverflow` and was advised to post it here.

Comment: StackOverflow is notoriously bad at getting the right site for a question to be asked on - that's why we aren't a migration target for them any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft discontinued the MDAC object set as 2005, and supported OSes as of XP (even server 2003 does not fully support MDAC, particularly WMI ODBC is not supported). Windows Vista and newer OSes only support WinDAC, which does not offer WMI via ODBC.

Side note: WMI isn't always the best interface to poke at, parts of it are [terribly broken](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974524) and even doing mundane queries can break your Windows installation.